# Java TimeUnit error

Tags: java, exception, time, jbutton

I wanted to make a Java program with Numberfields and a button.
When you click the button it waits and the time that was put in the Numberfield.The Integers work fine, but the function does not work.

Here is the code:

```
public void jButton1_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    sekunden = Integer.parseInt(jNumberField3.getText()); 
    minuten = Integer.parseInt(jNumberField2.getText());
    stunden = Integer.parseInt(jNumberField1.getText());
    zeit = sekunden + minuten*60 + stunden*60*60;//berechnet die zeit in sekunden
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(zeit);//here is the error
    System.out.println("zeit");
} // end of jButton1_ActionPerformed
```

The error message looks like this:

```
ES.java:78:27: error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(zeit);
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

Comment: Could you share your zeit decleration and a sample value of zeit taken from debug mode?

Comment: You need to use a try-catch on the sleep function.  Sleeping throws an InterruptedException in the event that Thread.interrupt is called during the sleep.  This information is available when you google the "unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown" ;; In addition, you could simply make the "jButton1_ActionPerformed" function throw the error but then you need to process it [the error] at one step back (the generated function that calls this function)

Comment: all variabels are declared and tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method call `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(zeit)` throws an `InterruptedException` which has to be caught:

```
public void jButton1_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
   try {
    sekunden = Integer.parseInt(jNumberField3.getText()); 
    minuten = Integer.parseInt(jNumberField2.getText());
    stunden = Integer.parseInt(jNumberField1.getText());
    zeit = sekunden + minuten*60 + stunden*60*60;//berechnet die zeit in sekunden
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(zeit);//here is the error
    System.out.println("zeit");
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
      //handle the exception
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle a potential `InterruptedException` that may happen when you call `sleep()`. This is why your code is getting a compilation error.

Please take a look at [Catching and Handling Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html) on JavaDocs to more details on exception handling.

In your case, you could easily solve it by handling the exception such as:

```
public void jButton1_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    sekunden = Integer.parseInt(jNumberField3.getText()); 
    minuten = Integer.parseInt(jNumberField2.getText());
    stunden = Integer.parseInt(jNumberField1.getText());
    zeit = sekunden + minuten*60 + stunden*60*60;//berechnet die zeit in sekunden
    try {
        // tries to call sleep
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(zeit);//here is the error
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // handles any possible exception during the call to "sleep()"
        e.printStackTrace(); // prints the exception stack trace to the console
    }
    System.out.println("zeit");
} // end of jButton1_ActionPerformed
```

Some good references in exception handling are:

- [Java exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625672/java-exception-handling)
- [Best practices in handling java exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803110/best-practices-in-handling-java-exceptions)